# Qt DBus Monitor Method Calls

Tags: c++, qt, dbus

I would like to know if there is an easy way **via QtDbus to "monitor" method calls** of a certain service. For example I would like when there is a Notify method call to org.freedesktop.Notifications to be able to "catch" it and read its arguments.

**Note***

I may have find a solution, which is using the dbus-monitor application but I would like to know if there is a better way through Qt Dbus library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this (with a bit of work) through QtDBus. Fundamentally, *any* client on a message bus can subscribe to any message -- limited only by the bus's security policy. (So there is no way to monitor an explicitly uncooperative application, unless you have debugging access to it or to the message bus.) The key is that you will want to use the `org.freedesktop.DBus.AddMatch` method on the bus itself:

```
// first connect our handler object to the QDBusConnection so that it knows what
// to do with the incoming Notify calls
// slotNotifyObserved() must have a compatible signature to the DBus call
QDBusConnection::sessionBus().connect("", // any service name
                                      "", // any object path
                                      "org.freedesktop.Notifications",
                                      "Notify",
                                      myImplementingQObject,
                                      SLOT(slotNotifyObserved(...)));

// then ask the bus to send us a copy of each Notify call message
QString matchString = "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications',member='Notify',type='method_call',eavesdrop='true'";
QDBusInterface busInterface("org.freedesktop.DBus", "/org/freedesktop/DBus", 
                            "org.freedesktop.DBus");
busInterface.call("AddMatch", matchString);

// once we get back to the event loop our object should be called as other programs
// make Notify() calls
```

The [DBus Specification](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-routing-match-rules) gives a listing of the various matching fields that could go in `matchString`.

To better see what is going on, [the QDBus documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdbus/qtdbus-index.html) suggests setting the environment variable `QDBUS_DEBUG=1` to cause your application to log information about its dbus messaging.

Comment: Hello bks. Based on your code if I don't register an object at "/org/freedesktop/Notifications" dbus sends an error of "UnkownObject" for this path. I did register an object at sessionBus and it is working this way but do I really need to register an object? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: DBus itself does not actually have a concept of "registering" an object: messages are simply sent to the application, which then figures out what to do with them. Qt, however, will only accept messages that are sent to an object that has been registered with it, AFAICT. So registering an object with Qt is probably the best solution. If you're using Qt 5.1 or higher, you might consider just registering a QDBusVirtualObject at "/" to handle everything.

Comment: When I register an object with
`registerObject("/org/freedesktop/Notifications", "org.freedesktop.Notifications", this)`
I get the error `No such interface 'org.freedesktop.Notifications' at object path
'/org/freedesktop/Notifications'`

Comment: Since DBus 0.31, `AddMatch` has been deprecated in favor of `BecomeMonitor`, a new but different API to monitor buses. Official docs: https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html